# Weird login problem on asp.net web application in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, authentication, forms-authentication

In my web application when i try to login in from Mozilla or chrome, it takes me to the correct url that im redirecting to after authentication, im using form-authentication.

But when i try to do that in IE, it just puts my intended URL in the query string as return  and gives me the login prompt again.

Does any one have any ideas as to why this might be and how can it be fixed.

To Redirect im using

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

This login was working even in IE before i put code to allow for access from an external application, which involves creation of new aspnet user if required. Can this be the problem.

Comment: Could you please mark your answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Its fixed was a simple matter of clearing browser data. :D</strike>

cookies and cache removed.

i just had to name the cookie ....lol......will never use un-named cookies ever :D

Comment: NOPE ITS BACK AGAIN. :( ...... BUT ONLY THAT NOW ITS FAILING WHEN I TRY TO LOAD IT IN AN IFRAME, EVEN THIS WORKED WHEN I CLEARED BROWSER DATA, ITS IN FITS AGAIN .

Comment: My gut feeling is that doing it in an iFrame might break some security rules implemented by the provider.

Comment: i just had to name the cookie ....lol......will never use un-named cookies ever :D

Comment: name your cookie?  did you just name it in Web.Config ?  I'm having the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your should to use [FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage.aspx) method.

Comment: i believe this has the same effect. Only that i can specify where to redirect to rather than the default value in the web.config. I think it has more to do with IE, because it is working in firefox and chrome